# Can I edit inside of a modal popup?

Tags: vb.net, edit, modalpopupextender

I have only found posts in which people using gridviews and modal popups need help with editing. However, I am not using a gridview so editing is not as simple as an edit within a gridview. The modal popup disappears when I click on the edit button. Here is what I have so far, but in the codebehind I get an error saying that my modal isn't declared.

In the image below, the little pencil image next to the close button is what I click on to edit the description. When I click on it, the modal disappears, so I cannot edit the text.

```
<!-- Descriptions -->
<asp:TabPanel ID="tab2"  runat="server" HeaderText="Descriptions">
<HeaderTemplate>Descriptions</HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ul class="info">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvDescriptions" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="dsAdminMarketingDescriptions" DataKeyNames="MarketingID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="item">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ViewDescriptionButton" runat="server"><%# 
                Eval("Title")%>
                </asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteDescriptionButton" runat="server" 
                Style="float:right;" AlternateText="" 
                ImageUrl="../../images/delete.png" CommandName="Delete" 
                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this 
                description?')" />
                <asp:Panel ID="ViewDescriptionPanel" runat="server" 
               CssClass="DescModalPopup">
      <div class="PopupHeader">View Description -- <%#Eval("Title") %>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelDescriptionButton" runat="server" 
                     ImageUrl="../../images/cancel.png" AlternateText="" 
                     Style="float:right;"/>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="EditDescriptionButton" runat="server" 
                     ImageUrl="../../images/edit.png" AlternateText="" 
                     Style="float:right;" CommandName="edit" AutoPostBack="false" />
                </div>
                <asp:Label ID="Description" runat="server" style="padding:2px;">
                <%# Eval("Data")%>
                </asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel> 
                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ViewDescriptionModal" runat="server" 
                 BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false" 
                 DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="true" 
                 PopupControlID="ViewDescriptionPanel" 
                 TargetControlID="ViewDescriptionButton" 
                 CancelControlID="CancelDescriptionButton">
                </asp:ModalPopupExtender>              
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>


Protected Sub EditDescriptionButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
  System.EventArgs)
    ViewDescriptionModal.Show()
End Sub
```

[image]

UPDATE: i changed the codebehind, but I still get an error saying ViewDescriptionModal is not declared.

```
Protected Sub EditDescriptionButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim myControl As Control = FindControl("ViewDescriptionModal")
    If (Not myControl Is Nothing) Then
        ViewDescriptionModal.Show()
    Else
        'Control not found
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:** I have created a second modal popup for edits and changed the Label to a Textbox to pull in information from the database to edit. I added a submit button, but when I click on it, I get an error saying something about it being potentially dangerous.

Does anyone have any experience with `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`

Comment: I'm not sure what the rest of your page looks like.  it is hard to tell what you are doing from here.

Comment: @MitchelSellers I added an image and a bit more code. I hope that helps explain a little better.

Comment: I have read that using an `UpdatePanel` will help keep the modal from refreshing but when I try to include it, I get an error saying that Panels cannot be inside of an `UpdatePanel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you may have luck if you use two modalpopupextenders, and two panels, one for viewing and one for editing.

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ViewDescriptionModal" runat="server" 
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false" 
DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="true" 
PopupControlID="ViewDescriptionPanel" 
TargetControlID="ViewDescriptionButton" 
CancelControlID="CancelDescriptionButton">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender> 

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="EditDescriptionModal" runat="server" 
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false" 
DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="true" 
PopupControlID="EditDescriptionPanel" 
TargetControlID="EditDescriptionButton">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender> 


<asp:Panel ID="ViewDescriptionPanel" runat="server" ... </asp:panel>              
<asp:Panel ID="EditDescriptionPanel" runat="server" ... </asp:Panel><code>
```

Comment: That sounds like it makes sense. I imagine that I just keep my edit button where it is, in the viewmodal. I created an editmodal, but when I click on the edit button, shouldn't it open the editmodal? Once again, I get an error saying the modal isn't declared.

Comment: I did a quick test and it worked for me, although my second modal just had a test string in it. Are you still using the EditDescriptionButton Click event?  Since it is set as the TargetControlID you shouldn't need to handle it in code behind.

Comment: Yeah I got rid of the code behind and when I click on the little pencil image in my modal it just refreshes the page and the modal disappears. How are you able to get the edit modal to show up?

Comment: Ok nevermind, must've had a typo. The second modal DOES show up. Great idea on adding an extra one to edit my info! Now I need to figure out how to make the text editable and I'm all set!

Answer (score 0):

try in your image button
 `autopostback="false"`

Comment: I tried that and the modal still disappears when I click on the button.

Comment: `ViewDescriptionModal.visble() = 'true'` in your button click event may help you.

Comment: I still get an error saying that ViewDescriptionModal is not declared. It doesn't make sense to me because that is the ID on the aspx page. Is there something wrong that I can't see?

Comment: use `findcontrol` method for it.

Comment: I edited the original post with the code I used with the `findcontrol` method and I still get the same error.

Comment: `Control ctrl = (Control)FindControl("ViewDescriptionModal")` `ctrl.visble() = 'true'`

Comment: `Dim ctrl = FindControl("ViewDescriptionModal")
        ctrl.Visible() = True` The way you wrote it gave errors so I converted it to vb, but it still posts back when I click on edit. I have no idea what to do

Comment: `.Show` is not a member of `system.web.ui.control` so I changed it to `.Visible` but it still will not keep the modal on the page